# How do I include Record Type in Account Name with NPSP using Household Account Model?

Tags: account, npsp, nonprofit-starter-pack, households

I would like to specify a custom Account Name that contains the Record Type in our NPSP deployment that uses Household Accounts model. We have four Contact record types so far: Volunteer, Client, Donor, Vendor.

In the **NPSP Settings** tab, I expected to be able to edit the **Household Name Settings** to something like ***{!LastName} Household ({!RecordType})*** yet this returns an error: *Error in Household Name Format: Invalid field RecordType for Contact.*

How do I format this config option to return the Contact Record Type in the Account Name?

Comment: The best resource for NPSP help is the Salesforce Foundation's [Power of Us Hub](https://powerofus.force.com/publogin).  There are many NPSP users and consultants in the various chatter groups, and the NPSP developers + Foundation staff are also active.  You can login to the Hub with your Salesforce username.